# Batch File to copy from an origin to multiple destinations

Tags: batch-file, file-io

I'm looking for a batch file to accomplish the following tasks:

1. Batch file to Look at the folder and sub folders of a location (for example: \server1\main\ and its sub folders) and copy the files based on the first 3 letter of the files' names to multiple folders corresponding to their names.
2. After the copy is finished I would like to move the original files/folder to an archive directory.

The file format is as follows: `AAA_xxx_xxx.jpg` - the first 3 letters of the file name is what we care about.

Example:

- Files `\\server1\main\AAA\AAA_xxx_xxx.jpg` will get copied to `\\server2\files\AAA\`
- Files `\\server1\main\BBB\BBB_xxx_xxx.jpg` will get copied to `\\server2\files\BBB\`

Comment: You don't specify what OS you're using -- it sounds like Windows, but that's not clear -- which is important.  Also, have you tried anything yet?

Comment: P.S. How do you determine whether to copy to server 1 or server 2?

Comment: Say `%filename%` equals `AAA_xxx_xxx.jpg` - `%filename:~0,3%` will therefore equal `AAA`. Look into [string manipulation](http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php). I also recommend that you provide insight into how you've already gone about trying to achieve this.

Comment: @EdCottrell: "Batch file" is a term commonly applied to Windows batch files (formerly MS-DOS batch files).

Comment: Batch file string manipulation is indeed what this question is essentially about. Apart from @unclemeat's useful link, you can also search this very site for ready solutions on the subject. Here's but one resolved question to start with: [Batch file to copy files based on part of filename from one server to another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11693446/batch-file-to-copy-files-based-on-part-of-filename-from-one-server-to-another)

Comment: @AndriyM: I know what a batch file is. It's not 100% clear from the question that the OP really means a Windows batch file, however. Many novices in *nix systems (myself included, once upon a time) don't know the correct terminology or use of forward and back slashes.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, but yes this batch file is for windows. link was provided can do the copy what do you guys suggest to do for doing the archive after the files have been copied. i would like to move the sub-folder including its files to be moved to a archive folder.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir\one"
SET "sourcedir2=U:\sourcedir\t w o"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
SET "targetdir=U:\targetdir"
FOR %%d IN ("%sourcedir%" "%sourcedir2%") DO (
 FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=_" %%a IN (
   'dir /b /a-d "%%~d\*_*.jpg" '
   ) DO (
  ECHO(MD "%destdir%\%%a\"
  ECHO(COPY /y "%%~d\%%a_%%b" "%destdir%\%%a\"
  ECHO(MOVE "%%~d\%%a_%%b" "%targetdir%\"
 )
)

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir`, `sourcedir2`, `destdir` and `targetdir` to suit your circumstances.

The required MD commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(MD` to `MD` to actually create the directories. Append `2>nul` to suppress error messages (eg. when the directory already exists)

The required MOVE commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(MOVE` to `MOVE` to actually move the files.  Append `>nul` to suppress report messages (eg. `1 file moved`)

The required COPY commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(COPY` to `COPY` to actually copy the files.

Oh - having done the work, I see I'm a victim of a reformatter and this question has whiskers. Oh well - maybe it'll help someone else.